# How to stop a timer immediatly and how to disable thread pool queuing?

Tags: c#

How can I stop a timer immediatly. When I use the code below running a lenghty job in the timer handler setting Auto=false doesn't stop the timer immediatly. To my opinion the timer thread is still running and after finishing the job it will terminate. How can I make the code clean up the timer thread when Auto is set to false, stopping a time consuming job running in it immediately??

Secondly, I don't want a thread to be queued in the thread pool , when IntervalSeconds elapses and the previous thread is still running completing a lenghty task. Is the code below the right way to do this ??

```
class AutoObject : IDisposable
{
    private bool m_bAuto;
    private System.Timers.Timer m_Timer = null;
    private int m_nIntervalSeconds = 60;
    private readonly object m_PadLock = new object();

    public event EventHandler AutoTimeElapsed;

    public bool StartInstantly { get; private set; }

    public virtual bool Auto
    {
        get { return m_bAuto; }
        set
        {
            if (m_bAuto != value)
            {
                DisposeTimer();

                if (value)
                {
                    m_Timer = CreateTimer(IntervalSeconds, true);           // Creates a running timer.

                    if (StartInstantly)
                        OnAutoTimeElapsed(EventArgs.Empty);
                }

                m_bAuto = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual int IntervalSeconds
    {
        get { return m_nIntervalSeconds; }
        set
        {
            if (m_nIntervalSeconds != value)
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("IntervalSeconds property must be greater than zero.");

                if (m_bAuto)
                {
                    DisposeTimer();

                    m_Timer = CreateTimer(value, true);                     // Creates a running timer.

                    if (StartInstantly)
                        OnAutoTimeElapsed(EventArgs.Empty);
                }

                m_nIntervalSeconds = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public AutoObject(bool bAuto, bool bStartInstantly)
    {
        StartInstantly = bStartInstantly;

        Auto = bAuto;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnAutoTimeElapsed(EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoTimeElapsed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
        if (bDisposing)
            DisposeTimer();
    }

    private System.Timers.Timer CreateTimer(int nIntervalSeconds, bool bEnabled)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        Timer.Interval = nIntervalSeconds * 1000;
        Timer.Enabled = bEnabled;

        Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);

        return Timer;
    }

    private void DisposeTimer()
    {
        if (m_Timer != null)
        {
            if (m_Timer.Enabled)
                m_Timer.Enabled = false;

            m_Timer.Dispose();      // Thread is still running ??

            m_Timer = null;
        }
    }

    // If the time needed to process a task is greater than the timer
    // interval I want to completely throw away the "extra" execution,
    // without queuing the thread. Is this the right way to do it ??
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bLocked = false;

        try
        {
            bLocked = Monitor.TryEnter(m_PadLock);

            if (bLocked)
                OnAutoTimeElapsed(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bLocked)
                Monitor.Exit(m_PadLock);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hav eyou looked into using Quartz.  It is available as an open source nuget package.  I've used it for similar applications.  It is very nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me I would not use a timer at all and instead have a loop on a separate thread which waits at the end of processing.

within the loop you can check whether a stop has been requested and exit out as early as possible.

Monitor.Pulse can be used to immediately exit any waiting threads.

This will finish the task, then wait for the interval before starting it again so it cant run more than once.

for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _stopRequested = false;
        private TimeSpan _interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        private readonly object _monitorLock = new object();
        private Thread _thread = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(this.DoWork);
            _thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        }

        void DoWork()
        {
            while (!_stopRequested)
            {
                lock (_monitorLock)
                {
                    //Do Processing, whilst Checking for whether stop requested has been set. If it has return out.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        if (_stopRequested) return;

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Processing: {i}");

                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    }

                    Monitor.Wait(_monitorLock, _interval);
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestStart()
        {
            _stopRequested = false;

            _thread.Start();

        }

        public void RequestStop()
        {
            _stopRequested = true;

            //Lock the monitor object
            lock (_monitorLock)
            {
                //Pulse the monitor lock to release it
                Monitor.Pulse(_monitorLock);
            }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RequestStart();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RequestStop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I will try this out.

Comment: Tried this out. Application hangs on a stop request.

Comment: I have just created a quick windows forms app with a start and stop button, this does not appear to hang when stopping. - See my edit with source code.

Comment: You cann't restart the thread. When restarting the systems throws a System.Threading.ThreadStateException.